# How to sort a group of elements using jquery sortable and prevent a spot from being placed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list of categories, each with their own questions below them. I want to sort all categories alongside with their questions.

With my current code I can only sort the category bar but the questions are left in place.

This is my html (questions and categories can be any amount because when creating them they can be added dynamically):

```
<span id="sortablecats" class="ui-sortable">
   <label class="categorytitle ui-sortable-handle" style="">jjjj</label>
   <div class="row ui-sortable-handle" id="questionrow">
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <p class="questionclass">hhhh</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="container text-right">
            <input type="radio" name="questionlist[jjjj][hhhh]" id="radio-1" value="ok" required="">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-1"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
            <input type="radio" name="questionlist[jjjj][hhhh]" id="radio-2" value="fout" checked="">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-2"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
            <input type="radio" name="questionlist[jjjj][hhhh]" id="radio-3" value="nvt">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-3"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <p class="questionclass">jjj</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="container text-right">
            <input type="radio" name="questionlist[jjjj][jjj]" id="radio-4" value="ok" required="" checked="">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-4"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
            <input type="radio" name="questionlist[jjjj][jjj]" id="radio-5" value="fout">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-5"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
            <input type="radio" name="questionlist[jjjj][jjj]" id="radio-6" value="nvt">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-6"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <label class="categorytitle ui-sortable-handle" style="">Testt</label>
   <div class="row ui-sortable-handle" id="questionrow">
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <p class="questionclass">test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="container text-right">
            <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Testt][test]" id="radio-7" value="ok" required="">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-7"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
            <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Testt][test]" id="radio-8" value="fout" checked="">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-8"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
            <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Testt][test]" id="radio-9" value="nvt">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-9"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</span>
```

And my js:

```
$( "#sortablecats" ).sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    connectWith: "#questionrow",
    cancel: "#questionrow"
  });
```

I have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkw138np/) to demonstrate what is currently happening

How can I make it so that I only sort a category with all its questions? And only be able to sort them above or below other groups (so not a group in the middle of another group)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put all of the sortable contents in the same child div and link them to the parent.

For example having the parent div like so :

```
<div id="sortMyContents">
    <div>Content to be draggable with everything inside</div>
    <div>Content to be draggable with everything inside</div>
</div>
```

Following this logic your code should be :

```js
$("#sortablecats").sortable({
  connectWith: "#questionrow",
  cancel: "#questionrow"
});
```

```css
/* Dropdown menu */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-success {
  background-color: #10355e !important;
  border: 1px solid #10355e !important;
}

.bar {
  height: 18px;
  background: green;
}

.savewpi {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.deletefileclass {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #10355e;
}

.btn-success:hover {
  background-color: #051d38 !important;
  border: 1px solid #051d38 !important;
}

.displaynonecoid {
  display: none;
}

.lijstnaamtitle {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #212529;
}

.lijsttitle {
  width: 85% !important;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
}

.lijstresult {
  background-color: #10355e;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: none;
}

.horscroll {
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}

.hiddenupload {
  display: none;
}

.addsubpage {
  display: none;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: #10355e !important;
}

.fileDisplayArea img {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}

.tarievenhead {
  background-color: #10355e;
  color: #fff;
}

.trinv {
  background-color: #edeaea;
}

.companylogo {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.headerlogo {
  max-height: 100px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.switch-field {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-title {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.switch-field input {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-field label {
  float: left;
}

.switch-field label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.container label {
  position: relative;
}

/* Base styles for spans */

.container span::before,
.container span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Radio buttons */

.container span.radio:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.addwerkplekinspectie input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.questionclass {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e9e9e9;
  height: 90%;
}

.nomarginleft {
  margin-left: 0px !important;
}

.inputtitles {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.borderbottom {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.radiotoggle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  margin-left: 60px;
  position: relative !important;
  right: 0px;
}

.container span.radio::before {
  left: -52px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #10355e;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.container span.radio::after {
  left: -49px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #6C788A;
  transition: left .25s, background-color .25s;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label span.radio::after {
  left: -27px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.categorytitle {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #10355e;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.switch-field label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-field input:checked+label {
  background-color: #A5DC86;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-field label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.switch-field label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

.deletedemployee {
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #10355e;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}

.deletewpi {
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #10355e;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}

.deletedtemplate {
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #10355e;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}

.addedemployee {
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #206b0a;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.filedeletedmessage {
  display: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #206b0a;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.resultmessage {
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #206b0a;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.resultmessageuser {
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #206b0a;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.deleteduser {
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #206b0a;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.manualmessage {
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #206b0a;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.resultmessageuseradded {
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #206b0a;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.editcontentmessage {
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #206b0a;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.fs-upload-input {
  background-color: #10355e;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.fs-upload-target {
  padding-top: calc(.375rem + 1px);
  padding-bottom: calc(.375rem + 1px);
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: 1.5;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.categorylist {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.sortwrap input {
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 85% !important;
}

.sortwrap {
  position: inherit !important;
}

.catinput {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dragndrop {
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #10355e;
  cursor: move;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 7px;
  position: relative;
}

.ui-state-highlight {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #113c69;
  width: 300px;
}

.wrapper {
  clear: both;
   !important;
}

.inspectiebutton {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.removebutton {
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-left: -90px;
}

.questionbutton {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.questioninput {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.removequestion {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.categorylist li {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.categorylist li input {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.questionlist li input {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.questionlist li {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#loginresult {
  background-color: #dc0b0b;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-show {
  display: block !important;
  padding: 4px 10px !important;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Einde dropdown menu */

.menuicon {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.backlink {
  color: #fff;
}

.addcontent {
  display: none;
}

.backlink:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.personeel {
  font-size: 90px;
}

.versions {
  display: none;
}

.green {
  color: #55af11 !important;
}

.red {
  color: #c31111 !important;
}

.versionlist {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.versionlist li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.versionlist i {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #10355e;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mtop-20 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.companylink {
  color: #0e3158;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.manualtitle {
  float: left;
}

.editmanual {
  float: right;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #113c69;
}

.wysiwyg {
  clear: both;
}

.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.menuliststyle {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menuliststyle a {
  color: #10355e;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.textcenter {
  text-align: center;
}

.logoheader {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.underlinelink {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #10355e;
}

.frontpageicon {
  color: #10355e;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.cover {
  object-fit: cover;
}

.pbottom-0 {
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.ptop-0 {
  padding-top: 0px !important;
}

.chapter {}

.font-10 {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.h45 {
  height: 45px;
}

.mtop10 {
  margin-top: 8% !important;
}

.font-12 {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.tabheight-100 {
  height: 100px;
}

.col-xl-custom {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
}

.dashicon {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #113c69;
}

.tabheight {
  height: 120px;
}

.greydark {
  color: #272727;
}

.padding-0 {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.shadowhover {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.shadowhover:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 50px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: inherit;
}

.bigheader {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.btnadd {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #10355e;
  border-color: #10355e;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bgblue {
  background: radial-gradient(at 50% -20%, #1967a9, #0a1832) fixed !important;
}

.btnadd:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #051d38;
  border-color: #051d38;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.actionbuttons {
  text-align: center;
}

.actionbuttons i {
  color: #0e3158;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.normblue {
  color: #10355e;
}

.btn-blue {
  background-color: #10355e !important;
  border: 1px solid #10355e !important;
}

.filestyle {
  background-color: #10355e;
}

.padding-025 {
  padding: 0.25rem !important;
}

.editwindowadmin {
  display: none;
}

.margininput {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.activebutton {
  background-color: #10355e;
}

.activebutton i {
  color: #fff;
}

.activebutton h4 {
  color: #fff;
}

.editcontent {
  float: right;
}

.editcontent i {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #10355e;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.nav-pills .nav-item.show .nav-link,
.nav-pills .nav-link.active {
  background-color: #10355e !important;
}

.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
}

.font-15 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

/* .h60{
  height: 60px;
} */

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .menuliststyle {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    max-width: 90%;
  }
  .btnadd {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #10355e;
    border-color: #10355e;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 15px !important;
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<span id="sortablecats" class="ui-sortable">
  <div>
   <label class="categorytitle ui-sortable-handle" style="">jjjj</label>
   <div class="row ui-sortable-handle" id="questionrow">
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <p class="questionclass">hhhh</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="container text-right">
            <input type="radio" name="questionlist[jjjj][hhhh]" id="radio-1" value="ok" required="">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-1"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
            <input type="radio" name="questionlist[jjjj][hhhh]" id="radio-2" value="fout" checked="">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-2"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
            <input type="radio" name="questionlist[jjjj][hhhh]" id="radio-3" value="nvt">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-3"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <p class="questionclass">jjj</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="container text-right">
          <input type="radio" name="questionlist[jjjj][jjj]" id="radio-4" value="ok" required="" checked="">
          <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-4"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
          <input type="radio" name="questionlist[jjjj][jjj]" id="radio-5" value="fout">
          <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-5"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
          <input type="radio" name="questionlist[jjjj][jjj]" id="radio-6" value="nvt">
          <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-6"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="categorytitle ui-sortable-handle" style="">Testt</label>
    <div class="row ui-sortable-handle" id="questionrow">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <p class="questionclass">test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="container text-right">
          <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Testt][test]" id="radio-7" value="ok" required="">
          <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-7"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
          <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Testt][test]" id="radio-8" value="fout" checked="">
          <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-8"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
          <input type="radio" name="questionlist[Testt][test]" id="radio-9" value="nvt">
          <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-9"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great.

Comment: @twan happy to help :-)